# Creating Objects of same Class with different Functions at Compiletime

Tags: c++

atm I'm trying to find the best solution for creating objects(classes) with common properties but differ in one specific function. 
The reason I dont use a simple sub-class is, that I have about 50 "different" objects and I do not want to create a class for each of them.

Here is my attempt to do so:

```
class module{
public:
  //..constructor and stuff
  void (*work)();
}

int main(){
  module A = new module();
  A->work = [](mainclass* m_class) -> void {/*do smth specific */});
  //... continue with B,C,...
}
```

I wonder if this is the most elegant (or most horrible) way to do this, or if there is a better concept for that kind of task.

Comment: Any reason why you can't use the standard OO approach of making `void module::work(mainclass*)` a virtual function in `module`, and then deriving a different base class for each different implementation?  You would then need `m_ModuleList` to be a vector of pointers to `module` (or `unique_ptr<module>` or `smart_ptr<module>`, etc.)

Comment: Jeah I wanted to avoid creating 50 different sub-classes for just one (in most cases pretty short) function

Comment: @DieUsche: The function is always known at compile time?  Do the objeccts _have_ to be of the same class? Can that class be a template where the template parameter is the function to be called?

Comment: `std::function<void()> work;` would be more flexible than `void (*work)();`

Comment: yes, the function of the module is always known at compiletime. And no, the objects just have to be childs of a masterclass to store them in a STL. What do you mean exactly with "class be a template function"?

Comment: @DieUsche: If they're stored in a container, then the compiler doesn't know which object is attached to which function, since they'll all have the same type, so the function of `container[0]` is _not_ known at compile time.  (If you need it to be, you can use a `tuple` instead)

Comment: Whatever you do, ***don't*** store derived objects in an STL container of base class type -- this causes [object slicing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c), i.e. badness that the compiler won't object to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the class doesn't *have* to be exactly the same, use templates

```
template<void(*work_fn)(mainclass*)>
class module{
public:
  //..constructor and stuff
  void work(mainclass* p) {work_fn(p);}
};

void work_A(mainclass*) {/*do smth specific */};

int main(){
  module<work_A> A; //note, no new
  A.work(thingy);
}
```

If you do have to use exactly the same type (sometimes), then you can use dynamic dispatch on your class:

```
class module {
public:
  //..constructor and stuff
  virtual void work(mainclass* p);
};
template<void(*work_fn)(mainclass*)>
class module_impl : public module {
public:
  using module;
  void work(mainclass* p) {work_fn(p);}
};

void work_A(mainclass*) {/*do smth specific */};

int main(){
  std::unique_ptr<module> A(new module_impl<work_A>(););
  A->work(thingy);
}
```

However, this might be overkill.  Your idea may indeed be best if they're being stored in a container or whatever.

```
class module{
public:
  //..constructor and stuff
  explicit module(std::function<void(mainclass*)> workfunc) : work(std::move(workfunc)) {}

  std::function<void(mainclass*)> work;
};

int main(){
  module A([](mainclass* m_class) -> void {/*do smth specific */}); //note no new
  A.work(thingy);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a famous software design pattern called the "strategy pattern", which is probably what you want: changing behaviour at runtime. A nice tutorial (although for java, but immediately translatable to `C++`) is here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-NCgRD9-C6o&list=PLF206E906175C7E07&index=3

Comment: sorry, basic inheritance patterns were not the thing I was looking for, but a nice video for beginners though

Comment: @DieUsche, I may have put an incorrect link, there are a variety of design patters explained, one of them is the strategy patter, which uses composition not inheritance. Updated the link

Comment: Ah lright, I guess I will read through some articles refering to "strategy pattern" then ;)

Comment: I read through the basics and it's definately a more elegant way than mine. The thing is I don't really need to change behavior at runtime, so maybe there is a way to just do the task at compiletime (maybe through templates), but nice advice though!